# People Manager vs. People Manager SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, userprofilemanager

What's the difference between [People Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj667813.aspx) with fewer methods and [People Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.userprofiles.peoplemanager_methods.aspx) with more methods?

I am using `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll`. I created

```
PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(ctx);
```

but it doesn't have [SetSingleValueProfileProperty method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.userprofiles.peoplemanager.setsinglevalueprofileproperty.aspx) and many others. What did I do wrong? How can I use [this People Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.userprofiles.peoplemanager_methods.aspx) with more methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods are available only in newer libraries, so downloading [SharePoint Online SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038) anew and updating the references fixed the issue.

The answer was provided by Patrick Liang here: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e544c518-67cc-4743-9943-d2d28e8a9ec9/sharepoint-online-people-manager?forum=sharepointdevelopment